# Date last modified on homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to find a similar issue to this, so a redirect would be much appreciated. My question: I have inserted the following Javascript into the footer of my site, but, instead of just appearing on the bottom of the main page, the time stamp pops up all over... some of the links in the navigation bar don't link to a page, but to the time stamp. (i.e. About > Versioning = renders the date last modified). How do I anchor this to just the footer of the main page?

Thanks for the help!

Website: www.huondauvergne.org

Script:

```
var m = "This page was last updated: " + document.lastModified;
var p = m.length-8;
document.writeln("<center>");
document.write(m.substring(p, 0));
document.writeln("</center>");
```

Comment: I see the time stamp at the very bottom in iOS chrome

Comment: `document.writeln` is dangerous.  use `.innerHTML` instead to set content. Also, your site seems to be doing some weird includes server-side.

Comment: If you click "Huon d'Auvergne Digital Archive" in the top left, or About > Versioning, it will lead to a blank page with only the time stamp. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Like @andi, said document.write is not ideal.  Doing something like `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("center")).innerText = "Last modified: " + document.lastModified` might do what your after.

Comment: Whew! That fixed it. Thanks for your help and for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

Wrap your timestamp writing code in an if checking the current url path.

So if your main page is at www.abc.com, you could do

```
if (location.pathname == '/') {
   // Insert timestamp writing code here
}
```

If it were at www.abc.com/index.html, you'd do

```
if (location.pathname == '/index.html') {
  // Insert timestamp writing code here
}
```

Basically whereever your main page is in relation to the domain, is where you would check.

Option 2:

Javascript on the main page to insert the timestamp:

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <!-- Footer stuff -->
  <span id="lastModified"></span>
</footer>
```

Javascript/jQuery on main page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#lastModified").text('Last modified on ' + lastModified);
});
```